# How do i remove letters in a tuple without changing to a string

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.x

Long story short, I am making code for random sums, and have taken to using the operator import in order to make it easier and more efficient. However, when printing the result of this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul
ops = (add, sub, mul)
op = random.choice(ops)
print("What is",ranNum1,op,ranNum2,"?")
```

I get:

> What is 9 < built-in function sub > 3 ?

I have tried to remove the letters in the result, but it is a tupple, not a string, so this is not possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you want to have a symbol for the operation. `from operator import add, sub, mul` imports those functions, so when you put them in a string, you get the function object. You'll need to roll something with a dictionary.

Comment: I am trying to remove "< built-in function" and ">" from the print result

Comment: If it is impossible, would there be a way to get around it? I am trying to ask the question in a more basic way, eg 'What is 10 + 2 ?' I have tried to use if statements which use the print result of 'op' (< built-in function ... >) but this does not work: eg: if op == '<built-in function add>'
    print("What is", ranNum1,"+", ranNum2,"?")
elif op == '<built-in function sub>'
    print("What is", ranNum1,"-", ranNum2,"?")
else:
    print("What is", ranNum1,"*", ranNum2,"?")
userAnswer = int(input(""))

Comment: Read and understand Morgan's comment. You are printing out a *function object*. In order to print out a symbol (`+`, `-`, `*`), you will need to create a dictionary to map the functions to their associated symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__name__` to get the name but this will not be the symbolic operator:

```
>>> print("What is", ranNum1, op.__name__, ranNum2, "?")
What is 6 add 9 ?
>>> print("Answer:", op(ranNum1, ranNum2))
Answer: 15
```

Adding a dictionary allows you to print the symbolic operator so replace `ops` with a dictionary:

```
>>> ops = {add: '+', mul: '*', sub: '-'}
>>> op = random.choice(list(ops))
>>> print("What is", ranNum1, ops[op], ranNum2, "?")
What is 6 + 9 ?
```

Comment: 'sub' is not clear and might be confusing to the user of the program who knows nothing about programming so using `__name__` is should not be a way to go. You have not shown how the OP should randomly select an op from the ops dict.

Comment: @dopstar the random.choice of the OP would still work `op = random.choice(ops)` but I can add it for clarity.

Comment: `op = random.choice(ops)` wont work, you need to supply a list object to `random.choice`

Answer (score -1):

```
from operator import add, sub, mul
import random

ranNum1 = random.randint(0, 100)
ranNum2 = random.randint(0, 100)
ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul}
op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
while True:
    user_input = int(input('What is {0} {1} {2}?'.format(ranNum1, op, ranNum2)))
    if user_input == ops.get(op)(ranNum1, ranNum2):
        break
    print('Incorrent!')
print('Correct!')
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a user input, just a random generated expression

Comment: You dont have to say `list(opts.keys())` you can just say `list(ops)` and you dont have to say `ops.get(op)(...)` you can just say `ops[op](...)`